# DAC0808 doesn't want tranfer to analog

Tags: arduino-uno

my lecture gave us DAC lab. He asks to make a sawtooth waveform in 8 bit from Arduino and then connect it DAC0808 to produce an analog signal with an amplifier. So we made an a circuit. Checked it. It works. Then started to do the calculations and expected results. We have done that. And the last we make a program in the wiring language. I wanted to make a step further and made a program which accepts different inputs from serial and changes the types of waveforms. But when we tried to check the working circuit for somereason it didn't want to work. I checked the program on 8 LEDS and they all workign perfect. But we put i  ht ecircuit and check on osciliscope it shows 9.7 volts when it should have 0 or 5 volts. The bits still went to DAC inputs but DAC didn't translate them to analog output. [image]

The lecturer sure the problem is in my complex problem rather then in my circuit or maybe with my processor, but I noticed very strange voltage output. When I touch the HIGH input voltage on DAC by multimeter it gives that value out. He still thinks it's problem with the code because his simple version works. :c

- So if it is I want to know where?
- Or why i doesn't?

The code:

```
    //Global Variables
enum wave {SAWTOOTH = 49, TRIANGLE, SQUARE, SINE, TANGENT};
int incomingByte;
int lastState = 0;
int calcResult;
int binaryOutput;
int triangleCheck;
int squareCheck;
int squareCount;
int sineOutput;
int tangentOutput;
int pin[8];

//Prototypes
int bitConversion(int);

//Setup
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(250000);
  for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    pin[i - 2] = i;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())
    incomingByte = (int)Serial.read();

  Serial.print("Incoming Byte: ");
  Serial.write(incomingByte);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Last State: ");
  Serial.write(lastState);
  Serial.println();

  if (incomingByte != lastState)
  {
    lastState = incomingByte;
    calcResult = 0;
    triangleCheck = 0; 
    squareCheck = 0;
    squareCount = 0;
    sineOutput = 0;
    tangentOutput = 0;
    Serial.println("State changed!");
  }

  Serial.print("STATE:                 ");
  switch (lastState)
  {
    case (SAWTOOTH):
      Serial.println("SAWTOOTH WAVE");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      if (calcResult == 255)
        calcResult = 0;
      calcResult++;
      break;

    case (TRIANGLE):
      Serial.println("TRIANGLE WAVE");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      if (calcResult == 255 || !calcResult)
      {
        Serial.println("Triangle changed!");
        Serial.println();
        triangleCheck++;
      }
      if ((triangleCheck % 2))
      {
        Serial.print("ODD   ");
        calcResult++;
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("EVEN  ");
        calcResult--;
      }   
      break;

    case (SQUARE):
      Serial.println("SQUARE WAVE");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      if (squareCount == 255 || squareCount == 0)
      {
        Serial.println("Square changed!");
        Serial.println();
        squareCheck++;
      }
      if ((squareCheck % 2))
      {
        Serial.print("ODD   ");
        calcResult = 0;
        squareCount++;
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("EVEN  ");
        calcResult = 255;
        squareCount--;
      }
      break;

    case (SINE):
      Serial.println("SINE WAVE");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      calcResult = 128+128*sin(2*PI*100*(sineOutput/10000.0));
      sineOutput++;
      break;

    case(TANGENT):
      Serial.println("TANGENT WAVE");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      calcResult = 128+64*tan(2*PI*100*(tangentOutput/10000.0));
      tangentOutput++;
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("DEFAULT");
      Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
      calcResult = 0;
      break;
  }

  binaryOutput=calcResult;
  Serial.print("Binary Output: ");
  Serial.println(binaryOutput, DEC); 

  if (binaryOutput)
  {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if (binaryOutput >= bitConversion(i))
      {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], HIGH);
        binaryOutput -= bitConversion(i);
        Serial.print(1);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
      else
      {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], LOW);
        Serial.print(0);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
    }
  }

  else
  {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      pinMode(pin[i], LOW);
      Serial.print(0);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
  }
  Serial.println("\n\n");
  delay(50);
}

int bitConversion(int n)
{
  int result = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    result *= 2;
  return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things about your project

1. For a wave generator it's not a good idea to generate the signal in the main loop. The right way to do it is using timers and counters (and interruptions if it's necessary). This is because in a digital signal generator is important the sample frequency and the wave frequency, and generating the wave in the main loop could make delays that alters the frequency. Using counters you could also control the frequency of your output signal.

   By the way, you can do this the way you're doing it but as I say, it has its limitations.
2. Because you are using 8 bits for the output and it is represented with the `calcResult` variable, maybe you can consider making it a `byte` or an `unsigned char` (both are basically the same).
3. In the `calcResult` calculation for the sine wave, it says `calcResult = 128+128*sin(2*PI*100*(sineOutput/10000.0))` but it should be `calcResult = 128+127*sin(2*PI*100*(sineOutput/10000.0))` because other way you will have `calcResult=256` some times.
4. The variable `triangleCheck` is always increasing, this will cause you overflow. Although this could also give you the right behavior, it's a better way to use a boolean or a char taking 0 and 1 values. This also happens with `squareCheck`.
5. It seems that you are printing the text about the incomingByte all the main loop's iterations, I think this could be annoying (and also takes processing capacity).
6. Take a look at the tangent wave, there is the same problem with the overflow that I've mentioned in the sine wave. You should use the periodicity of the signals to do this. You should also consider that the tangent is an unbounded function so it will have lot of values over the 255 that your DAC accepts.
7. For the bit conversions you do in the final part, maybe you can do it with bit masks. This would be cleaner and easier to handle.
8. If you're not sure about your DAC, you could test it using a dip switch. Or if you have the possibility, use a signal generator, then an ADC, then your DAC and finally the oscilloscope. This way you'll be 100% that your DAC is working.
9. Have you tested your Arduino's outputs? You can connect leds with a resistance to your output pins and with the square signal you should see some pretty clear behavior.
10. For sin wave and tangent wave I suggest to take a look at the casting of the variable (float to int). Maybe there's no issue about how it's done, but is good to be sure about the information that you're handling.

Hope this can help you with your project a little at least.

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for troubleshooting this problem. Well I was aware of the most of this issues. But overall it doesn't have any concerns because the `bitConversion` sorts all those overflows